# How to include more then one JS in wordpress theme?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

i am trying to add two JS files in my website theme:

1. js/jscripts.js
2. js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js

The code that I am using:

```
function wptuts_scripts_with_jquery()
{
    // Register the script like this for a plugin:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/custom-script.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );
    // or
    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts_with_jquery' );
```

by usnig this function i can add only one JS file, how do i can add 2nd JS file. I am new to wordpress and PHP. Need Help!! :)

Comment: Where you have these js files? In theme js folder?

Comment: Really? You've just copy and pasted that directly from [a tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins--wp-24321) that explains exactly how to do what you're asking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function wptuts_scripts_with_jquery()
{

    // do this for plugin js
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/jscripts.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_register_script( 'drop-down', plugins_url( '/js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );


    // or this for theme js
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jscripts.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_register_script( 'drop-down', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js', array( 'jquery' ) );


    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'drop-down' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts_with_jquery' );
```